# Writing a text file with fprintf on matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a text file using fprintf on matlab. I use a for loop:

```
fID = fopen('fileName','w');
fSpec = cat(2,repmat('%s', 1, 3),'\n');
for k=1:10
    to_write = [num2str(k) ',' num2str(k*k)];
    fprintf(fID, fSpec, to_write);
end
fclose(fID);
```

A file is written, but on one line only. I tried opening it with gedit and matlab.

What is wrong?

Comment: maybe you need a line return char? `to_write = [num2str(k) ',' num2str(k*k), '\r\n'];`?

Comment: nope. I tried this one. The matlab documentation says to use it if you want to open your file with notepad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format specifier is somewhat weird.
`to_write` will be a plain string, so why do you construct fSpec to be `%s%s%s\n`?

If you want one line per loop, you can simply do:

```
for k=1:10
    to_write = [num2str(k) ',' num2str(k*k)];
    fprintf(fID, '%s\n', to_write);
end
```

EDIT:

In case `%s%s%s\n` was designed to match the three strings in `[num2str(k) ',' num2str(k*k)]`: This is not necessary.
The result of `[num2str(k) ',' num2str(k*k)]` will simply be a single string - so you only need one `'%s'` format specifier, instead of three.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I didn't know the whole line could be considered as a string

Comment: I overlooked the fact that a string should be printed to file, somehow I thought it needed to be an integer. +1 for providing the answer!

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question, but I think it is worth pointing out that The Right Way™ to do this is to replace the two lines in the loop by the single line `fprintf(fID, '%d,%d\n', k, k*k);`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find two little things in your code.

First, you want to hit return after writing each line, thus `\n`. Second, you were trying to write a string value using `fprint` since you were using `%s`, changing it to `%d` solved it I think!

So the updated code should read:

```
fID = fopen('fileName','w');
fSpec = cat(2,repmat('%d', 1, 3),'\n');
for k=1:10
    to_write = [num2str(k) ',' num2str(k*k)];
    fprintf(fID, fSpec, to_write);
end

fclose(fID);
```

Comment: it does work indeed! The only difference between your code and mine is that you replaced the %s by %d. why does it work? Isn't %s the specifier for the strings?

Comment: This does not make sense. Using `%d` will write each character in `to_write` as its integer value. Which surely is not intented...